# how to use resource Images in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, resx

I'm following this [blog](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx), every thing is fine. But i have a issue how to handle Resources Resx Image or calling by view.Here is my code snippet

```
   <img src=@Resources.mODIFYGUIDLINE class="map img-responsive" alt="Hajj MAp" width="1136" height="600" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Name of the [string] along with [Image name].extension

```
  <img src="~/[foldername]/@Resources.[string name]" class="map img-responsive" alt="Hajj MAp" width="1136" height="600">
```